# In activity log, no link to election comments

Tags: bug, comment, election

If you made or make a comment on the [nomination](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=nomination) page of the election it shows up in your activity log. However, unlike comments to questions, there is no link shown to the actual comment.

> Is this a bug?

If not, I do not understand the logic. It omits context, and context is important for understanding. Also, I have no idea what an arbitrary user would think - personally, I thought that meta activity was now being recorded on the "main" activity log. Then I wondered if the question had been deleted but the comments were sticking around. So please sort this. It is confusing.

Comment: I will point out that it is possible to obtain link to the comment - for example by looking at the source of the election page. But this type of link [does not expand in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18992160#18992160). (As opposed to links to comments on usual posts on main and meta.)

Comment: See also the main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169590/comments-on-election-nominations-arent-linked-in-user-profile and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts

Comment: @Martin Yes, sorry, I figured the links existed. My point is rather that they are not displayed. (Also, I notice that, by your links, the issue is over 2 years old!)

Comment: This has been fixed with the recent changes to the election UI. Relevant Meta SE post: [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979).